# The feminine of "He was a leading man of letters"

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-gender

"William Shakespeare was a leading man of letters".  What if we are talking about Florence Margaret Smith.  Miss Smith was a leading......    Would you, native speakers, say "woman" ?

Comment: She was a capital letter-writer.

Comment: Do you know the term [bas bleu?](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bas+bleu) It means a woman having literary or intellectual interests [syn: bluestocking].

Answer (score 2):

Though *woman/women of letters*  is less common than *man/men of letters* (see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=women%20of%20letters,woman%20of%20letters,men%20of%20letters,man%20of%20letters&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,women%20of%20letters;,c0;.t1;,woman%20of%20letters;,c0;.t1;,men%20of%20letters;,c0;.t1;,man%20of%20letters;,c0)), it is a known expression in the [literary](https://mobile.twitter.com/womenofletters) space.

Comment: I've checked your link and it seems that "woman/women of letters is, and has always been, barely 0%.

Answer (score 1):

*Woman of letters* is quite acceptable.

Definition of WOMAN OF LETTERS

1
:  a woman who is a scholar
2
:  a woman who is an author
First Known Use of WOMAN OF LETTERS

1818

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/woman%20of%20letters